# Ошибка double free or corruption

Tags: c, указатели, память

Есть следующий функции:
Функция, сохраняющая текст неизвестного размера в память (Переменная sentence отвечает за количество предложений):

```
char** text_input(char **text, int *sentence){
    int slen = 50;
    char ch;
    int symb = 0;

    while (ch != '\n'){
        text[*sentence] = (char*)malloc(slen * sizeof(char));
        while (ch != '.' && ch != '\n'){
            ch = getchar();
            if (ch == '\n'){
            break;
            }
            if (symb >= slen - 1){
                slen += 50;
                text[*sentence] = (char*)realloc(text[*sentence], slen * sizeof(char));
            }
            text[*sentence][symb++] = ch;
        }
        if (ch == '\n'){
        break;
        }
        ch = '\0';
        text[*sentence][symb] = ch;
        *sentence += 1;
        text = (char**)realloc(text, (*sentence + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        symb = 0;
        slen = 50;
    }
    return text;
}
```

И функция, удаляющая из текста одинаковые предложения:

```
char** text_redaction(char **text, int *sentence){
    int count = 0;
    for(int sentence1 = 0; sentence1 < *sentence - 1; sentence1++){
        for (int sentence2 = sentence1 + 1; sentence2 < *sentence; sentence2++){
            if (strlen(text[sentence1]) == strlen(text[sentence2])){
                for(int j = 0; j < strlen(text[sentence1]); j++){
                    if (toupper(text[sentence1][j]) == toupper(text[sentence2][j])){
                        ++count;
                    }
                }
                if (count == strlen(text[sentence1])){
                    free(text[sentence2]);
                    for (int l = sentence2; l < *sentence; l++){
                        text[l] = text[l+1];
                    }
                    text[*sentence - 1] = NULL;
                    sentence2 -= 1;
                    *sentence -= 1;
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return text;
}
```

При запуске вторая выдает ошибку: double free or corruption
Где ошибка?

Comment: "При запуске" чего? Как выглядит вызывающий код?

Comment: Реалок странный)

Comment: В каком месте "double free or corruption"? В какой строке? На каком входе? Почему эта информация отсутствует в тексте вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибок много.

- (Этот код тут уже много раз появлялся под другими никами. Это тоже вы?)

Функция `text_input`:

- Опять, как и раньше, первая итерация цикла проверяет неинициализированную переменную `ch`. Вы просто игнорируете то, что вам тут говорят?
- Чему равно `text` и `*sentence` на входе в функцию? Откуда нам должно быть видно, что к `text[*sentence]` вообще можно обращаться?
- Если чтение предложения завершилось `\n` (а не `.`), то нуль-терминации строки не делается, счетчик `*sentence` не увеличивается и предложение не "регистрируется" при чтении, как будто его и не было. Хотя память для него выделялась. Явная утечка памяти.

Функция `text_redaction`:

- Обнуление переменной `count` делается только если в результате проверки получилось `count == strlen(text[sentence1])`. А если равенство не выполняется, то что, эту переменную не надо обнулять?

  И вообще: что это за странная манера, присутствующая в реализациях обеих функций, инициализировать переменные для *следующей* итерации в конце *предыдущей* итерации. Возьмите в привычку простой принцип: переменные для данной итерации объявлять/обнулять/инициализировать в начале именно этой итерации. Тогда и ошибки такие пропадут сами собой.

Несмотря на общую кривизну, немедленных причин для "double free or corruption" в коде не видно, т.е. ошибка скорее всего в каком-то другом коде.